# Windows 7 increases volume randomly

Tags: windows-7, audio, volume-mixer

when listening to music or watching videos, the volume increases as if it'd account for music that has almost mute parts. This means that it shoves to volume to up to 60+ from 18 which is not too pleasant with my headphones. This happened while listening to music while not even working at the computer. One problem is, that i am unable to recreate this behaviour, even when listening to the same song it doesn't appear again.

I know it the other way round when it shortly drops due to communication software (which i disabled completely already).

[Windows Speaker Settings/Communication Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWbSA.png)

My Setup consists of an Asus Xonar U7 and "normal" headphones. I experienced the problem now since yesterday. I tried to install other languages for TTS output. Which didnt not work out as expected and i deinstalled them shortly after that. (I mention this just as it overlaps with the problem and might be a cause of this). Is there any accesibility option i might have enabled by mistake that raises the volume levels when source material is almost silent?

I already checked for stuck keys on my keyboard media controls. That was not the case. And i tried to disable that applications have complete control over the headphones which didn't help either.

Thanks for your support in advance.

Edit 1: tried using safemode but the sound driver won't work, is it safe to enable it via regedit changes? E.g. like here: [How to enable audio in safe mode](https://superuser.com/questions/354325/how-to-enable-audio-in-safe-mode)

Edit 2: I Checked the Xonar U7 panel for 'automatic gain control' but did not find such a setting, neither did i find anything like this on the speaker/headphone windows settings.

[Xonar Software + Windows Settings + Foobar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdW0y.png)

The problem did happen when using foobar, but also when watching youtube via chrome. The foobar volume level keeps the same too, so i suppose this might not be the troublemaker. Only the Windows volume bar did actually adjust randomly, the others kept on the same level.

Comment: Are you sure that an unseen application is not the culprit? Try booting your computer in safemode with networking, and see if you still have the same problem.

Comment: The Problem with that is, that i cannot really replicate the issue, my only hope would be that it'd happen during that test period. Nonetheless i just rebooted into safe mode and i will report back, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have special headphone or sound software, you might want to check if you have 'automatic gain control' enabled.

If you are listening through a media player such as VLC, it has a volume leveling feature as well.

It could be your sound card as well, in that case you would open volume control, double click the speaker, and disable enhancements on the enhancements tab.

If you could provide more info, that would be great.

Comment: thanks for providing more possible sources of the error, i tried to give you more information about my setup, i hope this helps.

Comment: I guess that none of the things that I listed could be the culprit, since they all look fine to me. It's most likely a rogue program or system software that's causing this problem. The only thing I can propose is using [Process Explorer](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/processlock.htm) to see if anything interacts with your audio programs.