# Window 10 safe mode - enable sound

Tags: windows-10, audio

I'm trying to enable sound in safe mode.

I followed these steps [How to enable audio in safe mode](https://superuser.com/questions/354325/how-to-enable-audio-in-safe-mode), but from step 10 I had a problem:

[image]

I tried to google but no-one is talking about this problem.

Comment: **I know little about Windows** but I *guess* if the key is there then you don't need to create it. Pretend the old key is the one you created and proceed. If later you need to create another object and it's there, then it's there; the same story.

Answer (score 0):

You have already created `New Key #1`, and it's clearly found in your
image on the left column.

Left-click the key, and you will see a `(Default)` entry on the right.
Double-click on the entry to edit it and continue.

Note that if the audio driver is not from Microsoft, there is a chance
that it will not work in Safe mode.